# There exists an infinite set $S\subset \mathbb R^3$ such that any $3$ vectors in $S$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

There exists an infinite set $S\subset \mathbb R^3$ such that any $3$ vectors in $S$ are linearly independent.

Start with a basis $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.Take a vector not in any coordinate plane,call it $v_4$.It is possible to choose a vector $v_5\notin span \{v_i,v_j\}$ for all $i,j=1,2,3,4$.Choose $v_6\notin span \{v_i,v_j\}$ for all $i,j=1,2,3,4,5$.Continue this process of choosing $v_{n+1}\notin span\{v_i,v_j\}$ (for each $i,j=1,2,...,n$).Thus we obtain an infinite set $S=\{v_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ in which now three vectors are coplanar.So,any three vectors of $S$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb R^3$.

Is my solution correct.Can someone provide some alternative solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You might want to elaborate exactly why you can keep choosing these points (e.g. the set of points you cannot choose is a finite union of planes, and the finite union of sets with empty interior must have empty interior).

You can also take the (uncountable) set of vectors $(1, t, t^2)$ where $t \in \Bbb{R}$. Then any set of three points is linearly independent, using the [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: Thanks,it was a good idea.

Comment: how is my method with the cone?

Answer (score 2):

You also have an explicit solution : $v_n=(1,n,n^2)$.

Comment: How is my method?..................

Comment: See the cone method.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar I think you should ask this as a separate question

Comment: But it is an answer to the same question and I thought of it later,when these answers were already posted.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar "How is my cone method answer" is a question, not an answer (even though it is about an answer)

Comment: I actually wanted to know your opinion about the answer,to me it seems ok.

Comment: I also wanted to tell you about an alternative way of thinking of this problem,as you helped me to solve this problem earlier,I thought I should share this new idea.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Take any three distinct vectors whose line of support lies on a cone with vertex at origin and we are done.Clearly no three distinct vectors satisfying the above property are coplanar because any plane through origin can intersect the cone at $2$ lines at maximum.